# OAuthCallbackRoute › for an OAuth callback › on successful OAuth callback › on successful token fetching › uses the received code to fetch an auth tok

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

OAuth:

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

import AuthenticationContext from './AuthenticationContext';

function OAuthCallbackRoute() {
  const { fetchToken, callbackPath, setError } = useContext(AuthenticationContext);
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname !== callbackPath) return;

    async function completeLogin(code: string, state: string) {
      if (await fetchToken(code)) navigate(decodeURIComponent(state));
    }

    const successRedirectPathRegex = /\?code=(\S+)&state=(.+)/;
    const errorRedirectPathRegex = /\?error=(\S+)&error_description=(.+)&state=(.+)/;

    const successPathMatch = location.search.match(successRedirectPathRegex);
    if (successPathMatch) {
      const [, code, state] = successPathMatch;
      completeLogin(code, decodeURIComponent(state));
    }

    const errorRedirectPathMatch = location.search.match(errorRedirectPathRegex);
    if (errorRedirectPathMatch) {
      const [, error, errorDescription] = errorRedirectPathMatch;
      setError(${error} - ${decodeURIComponent(errorDescription)});
    }
  }, [fetchToken, navigate, location, callbackPath, setError]);

  return null;
}

export default OAuthCallbackRoute;
```

OAuth Test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { OAuthCallbackRoute } from '..';
import AuthenticationContext from '../AuthenticationContext';

const delay = async (ms: number) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });

describe('OAuthCallbackRoute', () => {
  let history: any;
  let historyReplace: any;
  let fetchToken: any;
  let setError: any;
  const originalError = global.console.error;

  beforeEach(() => {
    history = createMemoryHistory();
    global.console.error = jest.fn();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    global.console.error = originalError;
  });

  function App() {
    return (
      <AuthenticationContext.Provider
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-constructed-context-values
        value={{
          fetchToken,
          callbackPath: '/oauth',
          setError,
          authenticated: true,
          authenticating: false,
          authorize: () => {},
          logout: () => {},
          getToken: () => 'xyz',
        }}
      >
        <Router history={history}>
          <OAuthCallbackRoute />
        </Router>
      </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
    );
  }

  describe('for an OAuth callback', () => {
    describe('on successful OAuth callback', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        history.replace('/oauth?code=xyz&state=%2Ffoo');
        historyReplace = jest.spyOn(history, 'replace');
      });

      describe('on successful token fetching', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          fetchToken = jest.fn(() => true);
        });

        it('uses the received code to fetch an auth token', () => {
          render(<App />);
          expect(fetchToken).toHaveBeenCalledWith('xyz');
        });

        // it('redirects to the referrer path', async () => {
        //   render(<App />);
        //   await delay(100);
        //   expect(historyReplace).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
        // });
      });

      describe('on failed token fetching', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          fetchToken = jest.fn(() => false);
        });

        it('does not redirect to the referrer path', async () => {
          render(<App />);
          await delay(100);
          expect(historyReplace).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
      });
    });

    describe('on error included in callback', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        setError = jest.fn(() => true);
        history.replace(
          '/oauth?error=access_denied&error_description=Service%20not%20found&state=%2Ffoo',
        );
        historyReplace = jest.spyOn(history, 'replace');
      });

      it('does not redirect to the referrer path', async () => {
        render(<App />);
        await delay(100);
        expect(historyReplace).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      });

      it('puts the error on the context', async () => {
        render(<App />);
        expect(setError).toHaveBeenCalledWith('access_denied - Service not found');
      });
    });
  });

  describe('for a non-OAuth path', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      history.replace('/random-path');
      historyReplace = jest.spyOn(history, 'replace');
    });

    it('does not attempt to fetch a token', async () => {
      render(<App />);
      await delay(100);
      expect(fetchToken).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('does not redirect', async () => {
      render(<App />);
      await delay(100);
      expect(historyReplace).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

After upgrading react=router-dom v6.21.1 and @types/react-router-dom v5.3.3, In the above OAuth file getting error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')"

Error:
FAIL  packages/auth/src/*tests*/OAuthCallbackRoute.test.tsx
● OAuthCallbackRoute › for an OAuth callback › on successful OAuth callback › on successful token fetching › uses the received code to fetch an auth token

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

  13 |
  14 |     async function completeLogin(code: string, state: string) {
> 15 |       if (await fetchToken(code)) navigate(decodeURIComponent(state));
     |                                   ^
  16 |     }
  17 |
  18 |     const successRedirectPathRegex = /\?code=(\S+)&state=(.+)/;

  at pathname (node_modules/react-router/lib/components.tsx:448:5)
  at Component (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14985:18)
  at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17356:20)
  at updateFunctionComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19063:16)
  at HTMLUnknownElement.apply (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3945:14)
  at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
  at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:350:25)
  at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:286:3)
  at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:233:9)
  at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:104:17)
  at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:241:34)
  at Object.dispatchEvent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3994:16)
  at apply (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
  at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23964:7)
  at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22779:12)
  at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22707:5)
  at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22670:7)
  at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22293:18)
  at callback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11327:26)
  at eventHandler (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:12)
  at Scheduler_runWithPriority (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11276:10)
  at runWithPriority$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11322:9)
  at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11309:3)
  at flushSyncCallbackQueue (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21893:9)
  at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16139:5)
  at setStateImpl (node_modules/react-router-dom/index.tsx:856:11)
  at apply (node_modules/history/cjs/history.js:178:24)
  at apply (node_modules/history/cjs/history.js:196:23)
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at Object.forEach [as notifyListeners] (node_modules/history/cjs/history.js:195:15)
  at notifyListeners (node_modules/history/cjs/history.js:826:23)
  at setState (node_modules/history/cjs/history.js:856:7)
  at Object.callback [as confirmTransitionTo] (node_modules/history/cjs/history.js:168:7)
  at confirmTransitionTo (node_modules/history/cjs/history.js:844:23)
  at node_modules/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx:242:62
  at navigate (packages/auth/src/OAuthCallbackRoute.ts:15:35)
```

Auth Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "name/auth",
  "version": "2.4.1",
  "description": "Authentication utilities",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/name/react-tools/packages/auth/README",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/name/react-tools.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/name/react-tools/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@name/react-hooks": "^1.2.3",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "is-url": "^1.2.4",
    "js-base64": "^3.1.3",
    "randombytes": "^2.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.1",
    "sha.js": "^2.4.11"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.2.1",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "8.0.1",
    "@types/is-url": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/randombytes": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/sha.js": "^2.4.0",
    "cross-fetch": "3.1.5",
    "fetch-mock": "9.10.3",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.0"
  }
}
```

React-tooling Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@name/react-tools",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf node_modules packages//dist packages//node_modules packages/*/tsconfig.tsbuildinfo",
    "compile": "tsc -b tsconfig.json",
    "lint": "eslint . --max-warnings=0",
    "pretest": "npm run compile",
    "test": "jest",
    "prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "publish": "npx changeset publish",
    "version": "npx changeset version && npm i"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@changesets/cli": "^2.25.2",
    "@types/jest": "29.2.3",
    "eslint": "8.33.0",
    "jest": "29.3.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "29.3.1",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "29.0.3",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) hook to access/read the `code` and `state` (*and other*) URL search params. It's simpler than trying to string parse/REGEX the `location.search` value. What is the value of `successPathMatch` in the `OAuthCallbackRoute` component during the test? What is the value of `state` in `completeLogin`?

Comment: successPathMatch would be an array ['?code=xyz&state=%2Ffoo', 'xyz', '%2Ffoo']. and  In the completeLogin function, the state parameter would hold the value '%2Ffoo'.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was able to reproduce myself. I'm unable to reproduce the specific error message you have though. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: After "npm run clean" command I am facing this issue, Before that I didn't get this error even.
Any possible way that we can see it here.

Because I am not able to go forward and run with this error.

Comment: What does that `clean` script do? (*Share your package.json file*) You may need to re-run `npm install` again to install dependencies prior to using `npm run start`.

Comment: ran `npm install`  but still facing same issue here `npm run clean` command do `"rimraf node_modules packages//dist packages//node_modules packages/*/tsconfig.tsbuildinfo"`

Comment: Added Package.json file for auth and react-tools in the above question with edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an invalid dependency on `@types/react-router-dom`. These are React-Router-DOM (RRD) v5 type bindings but you are using RRDv6. Remove this dependency and see if that clears anything up.

```
npm uninstall @types/react-router-dom
```

RRDv6 also uses `history@5`, so you also have a dependency conflict here with `history@^4.10.1`. Remove this dependency if you have no need for it directly,

```
npm uninstall history
```

otherwise, upgrade to `history@5` since it looks like you do use it in your unit test suite

```
npm install history@5
```

Comment: Yes, Upgrade History worked, Thank you so much